# What is making these subnavs expand?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking at http://voky.com.ua/showcase/sky-mega-menu/examples/demo-personal.html and I can't figure out what is making the subnavs expand. For example, hover over "Portfolio" and see the subnav expand. I've inspected all the elements around the nav items and I can't find any CSS3 `transition` and I also can't see Javascript adding any `style` attributes to the elements or adding any classes.

Comment: Inspect page source, then... :) There is an answer... Somewhere at the very top of the page...

Comment: Just a small observation - You will find that you get more answers if you mark the correct ones as the accepted answer. Most people wont bother to answer your questions if you have a history of not marking questions as accepted (which you do). When you mark answers as correct, the author gets credit, and the next person that searches for the same can see which was the correct answer. Everybody wins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this;

**The expanding effect** is achieved by setting the `scale` property to `(0,0)` when the menu is closed and then `(1,1)` when its visible, and having a `transition` property for the animating timing. Here are the relevant lines;

```
/* line 60 */
.sky-mega-menu li > div {
  ...
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
}

/* line 374  */
.sky-mega-menu-anim-scale li > div {
  -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
}

/* line 380 */
.sky-mega-menu-anim-scale li:hover > div {
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

**The visibility** of the submenu on hover is achieved by setting it's `opacity` to 0 and then 1 when you hover on the respective `li`

```
/* line 60 */
.sky-mega-menu li > div {
  ...
  opacity: 0;
}

/* line 101 */
.sky-mega-menu li:hover > div {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS sheet named "sky-mega-menu.css" the div next to the li tag being hovered is set to 1 which make it visible.

```
.sky-mega-menu li:hover > div {
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
```